# what is the timer job responsible for SharePoint web application deletion?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, web-application

I am deleting a web application through central administration, but it takes too long to delete all IIS settings from the servers in the farm.

Is there a timer job or service that needs to be run on each node?

Answer (score 0):

If it is taking too much time, i would use the powershell to delete the web application.

I think either CPU/ ram on the sharepoint server is not enough or same hardware issue on the SQL server.

Please try increasing the value of Ping Maximum Response Time, Shutdown Time Limit and Startup Time Limit from default to 400 and create new web application again.You could go to IIS Manager > Application pools > Central admin appool